# Find surroundings numbers in lists in lists Python

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble finding surrounding numbers in list in list environment. The idea is that the list underneath each other form a grid.

```
grid= [[1, 5, 4, 1], 
       [2, 5, 3, 2], 
       [6, 3, **6**, 3], 
       [1, 4, 2, 1]]
```

The function I try to write has as given value the position of a number and the grid itself. The program should find the surrounding numbers. e.g. with this

```
>>> grid= [[1, 5, 4, 1], [2, 5, 3, 2], [6, 3, **6**, 3], [1, 4, 2, 1]]
>>> neighbours(2, 2, grid)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

In this example the element of choice is the bold 6.
I have no idea how to do this without constantly going out of indexes or making the code extremely difficult.

Any help would be appreciated a lot

Comment: do you have numpy or pandas installed?

Comment: Use a numpy array. If you don't know how to add numpy, simply type this line in windows cmd : "py -3.6 -m pip install numpy" and replace 3.6 by your version of python.

Comment: I work with pycharm and anaconda if that helps (sorry I am very new at this )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the neighbors and the cell itself, then remove the cell itself.

```
def neighbours(i, j, grid):
    vals = sum((row[j-(j>0):j+2] for row in grid[i-(i>0):i+2]), [])
    vals.remove(grid[i][j])
    return set(vals)
```

Comment: elegant way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `slice` object.

```
def neighbor(i, j, grid):
    cut_rows = slice(max(i-1, 0), i+2)
    rows = grid[cut_rows]
    cut_cols = slice(max(j-1, 0), j+2)
    throw_row = 0 if max(i-1, 0) == 0 and i != 1 else 1
    throw_col = 0 if max(j-1, 0) == 0 and j != 1 else 1
    rest = [r[cut_cols] for r in rows]
    throw_away_center = rest[throw_row].pop(throw_col)
    flat = [i for j in rest for i in j]
    return set(flat)
```

Updated to cope with 0,0 and 1,1 as well.
But now it's looking quite clonky the whole thing...

Comment: this seems to work unless i have following input: neighbor(0, 0, [[1, 5, 4, 1], [2, 5, 3, 2], [6, 3, 6, 3], [1, 4, 2, 1]]). Where i get an index out of range when the throw away center tries to preform. Is this the error you mean? The checks then you mean an "if"-statement?

Comment: yepp, that's why the others have `max` in their code.

Comment: how do you want this to wrap, what is your expected output for 0,0?

Comment: my expected output is 2 and 5 because 2 would be right to 1 and 5 be underneath 1

Comment: oki, so you just want the corner, then the `max` trick should do, hold on and I'll update the code with that.

Comment: aha, did not check that one, so another fix to do... I mainly do this as a brain exercise :-)

Answer (score 0):

We need to first create a `list` of all the neighbours, then return this as a `set`:

```
def neighbours(r, c, l):
    ns = []                             #declare a neighbours list
    if r > 0:                           #check if our row is greater than 0
        ns += l[r-1][max(0, c-1):c+2]   #add to the neighbours the row - 1
    if r < len(l)-1:                    #if not the last row
        ns += l[r+1][max(0, c-1):c+2]   #add row + 1 to the neighbours
    if c > 0:                           #if column is greater than 0
        ns.append(l[r][c-1])            #add the element to the left
    if c < len(l[r])-1:                 #if column less than the right edge
        ns.append(l[r][c+1])            #add the element to the right
    return set(ns)                      #return the neighbours as a set
```

and some test to show it works:

```
>>> neighbours(2, 2, grid)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> neighbours(0, 0, grid)
{2, 5}
>>> neighbours(3, 3, grid)
{2, 3, 6}
```

Comment: Wow...you could at least make it a bit more readable. The point here is not to win a code-golfing competition, but actually make OP understand what you did :p Nicely done anywayz

Comment: @Cajuu' There was actually a mistake anyway which I found when testing other values! So I have made the function *extra* clear now **:)**

Comment: @joeIddon this works great but for some few examples where it somehow leaves out the neighbor on the right. E.g. neighbors(4, 3, [[4, 3, 6, 4, 3], [2, 1, 5, 2, 1], [5, 7, 8, 7, 5], [4, 3, 6, 4, 3], [2, 1, 5, 2, 1]]) gives me the following result {3, 4, 5, 6} forgetting the last 1.

Comment: @LibertyVerleysen Sorry about that! There was a small indexing mistake where I switched a `r` for a 0. All fixed now :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code :

```
def neighbours(m, i, j, dist=1):
neighbors = []
i_min = max(0, i-dist)
i_max = i+dist+1
j_min = max(0, j-dist)
j_max = j+dist+1
for row in m[i_min:i_max]:
    neighbors.append(row[j_min:j_max])
# neighbors will hold all the neighbour elements as a list
# flatten the list to get the required outpout format
flat_list = [item for sublist in neighbors for item in sublist]
#remove duplicates from the list
flat_list = list(set(flat_list))
# remove the elemnt in question as it's not required for the output
flat_list.remove(grid[2][2])
return flat_list
```

This will give you all the neighbours , m = grid, i,j = 2,2 in your case.
Note : This example is placed to understand each step and can be modified to get the required output .

Comment: this looks like the right approach, but isn't `m` an `int`, in which case `m[i_min:i_max]` will not work.

Comment: sorry , forget to mention you may have to convert list of list to a flat list , will give a look at this tommorrw, sorry for typos

Comment: Is there a way to flatten these before input ? because my input are lists in lists. Already thanks a lot to both of you